# Force older version of vuejs devtools or download older version

Tags: vue.js, vue-devtools

Recently vue devtools was updated to a newer version. I am using the devtools heavily to check my vuex store. After the update the data does not show anymore. The data is updated after mutations but not shown in the devtool.

Does anyone know how to use the older version again?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All releases can be found on their Github page: [Here](https://github.com/vuejs/vue-devtools/releases)

Download your preferred version, then follow the steps written under [Manual installation](https://github.com/vuejs/vue-devtools#manual-installation)

Comment: I don't see any Manual Installation instructions on the link, nor on the `Documentation` link on that page?

Answer (score 2):

You can install the legacy dev tools [extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/vuejs-devtools/iaajmlceplecbljialhhkmedjlpdblhp/related) for Chrome.

See more info on the [documentation](https://devtools.vuejs.org/guide/installation.html#legacy)

Answer (score 1):

There is a **`Settings`** tab on the newer version which allows you to keep the Veux store synchronized at all times.
All you need to do is to enable it.

[image]

Comment: Did that, my browser freezes when the store gets generated/loaded, it's really big..

Comment: I see, then it makes sense to leave the autoloading of the state disabled for the latest version or else reinstall the older version.